# Cannot find Conda Environment after Docker Pull in PyCharm Professional

Tags: docker, pycharm, conda, fedora

I would like to use a Conda environment I created with a Docker pull in PyCharm professional. However, after the Docker pull, PyCharm is not able to find the Conda environment even if I specify the path. I think it has to do with when Docker file is pulled in the container I see

> /usr/bin/python3

Therefore, do I need to edit and specify where the Conda environment is?

I fairly new to this. Therefore any help would be appreciated.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6W1X.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlYSU.png)